# What is a good way to implement composition in Java?

Tags: java, composition

The following classes display the concept of `Composition` in Java:

```
//Imagine constructors, accessors & mutators has already been created..

class Person{
    private String name;
    private Job job;    //Person has Job
}

class Job{
    private String name;
    private double salary;
}
```

**My question is:** If I want to get the salary from Person, which of the following 2 options is a better practice?

**1.** Get job of person, then get salary from job of person

```
System.out.println( person.getJob().getSalary() );
```

### OR

**2.** Create a getSalary method in person, so I can do this:

```
System.out.println(person.getSalary());
```

Create a method to get salary from job first.

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private Job job;
    public static double getSalary(){    //Is doing this redundant and bad practice?
        job.getSalary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I find `method 2` a bad practice, however after reviewing lecture materials from different universities, one university incline towards `method 1`, while the other university incline more towards `method 2`. That's why I want to confirm with the experts here which is a better and perhaps safer practice.

Comment: Both are valid. It all depends if you consider Job as a public property of the person, that should be exposed as is, or as an implementation detail that shouldn't be part of the public API of the person. It also depends if Job is mutable and if you want to allow user of the API to modify a job directly, without going through methods of the Person.

Comment: I think not every person gets salary say housewife only people who do job (here as well not all people get paid but mostly) gets paid. So i would go for option 1.

Comment: @almasshaikh So are you saying logically, `method 1` makes more sense?

Comment: The advantage I can see of implementing a [Proxy Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), which is option 2, is that the user no longer needs to *know* anything about where that salary comes from. Some people might not have a job but still have a regular income (owning the lease to land, for example). In this case, they have an income and not a job. It wouldn't make sense to create `NoJob` type of Job, so in this case you need to calculate salary without Job. Hence why I think it is better to go with the latter, rather than the former.

Comment: What you are showing is not **composition**, there is no such relation in between a person and a job. It is simple **association**, a **person** has a **job** but is not composed of a job. A **job** is done by a **person** but is not composed of a person. And Salary is just an attribute of a job. No **composition**.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 is a little bit better than method 1 because the code that gets the salary from a person is not dependent on any kind of `Person->Salary` relation implementation. You are free to change the way the salary is computed. In real life you can ask somebody what is is salary without knowing anything about his job. In your code, a liar can even returns an imaginary salary for him, etc.

To be honest I insist on the fact that method 1 cannot be considered as bad or false in any way, it has only small disadvantage in common situations...

Comment: What about gun and bullets. Is it composition or aggregation or association?

Comment: Simple association! A gun is not composed of bullets (neither the contrary). A gun is not an aggregate of bullets for the same reason. Your car is an aggregate of its wheels, doors, seats, etc (a seat may exists outside a car). An house is composed of rooms (rooms doesn't exists outside houses).

Answer (score 0):

Generally and personally I like method 1 because every redirection (how call this right?) make code a little bit more complicated. Imagine whole code has redirections for every relation. Even it's harder to communicate: 'do you mean Person.Salary or Person.Job.Salary?'.

But in your example I prefer method 2 because I can imagine extend Person to have multiple jobs or jobs beside pension or like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Law" saying that option number 1 should be avoided, it's the [Demeter's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) aka **principle of least knowledge**

in particular

> an object **A** can request a service (call a method) of an object
>   instance **B**, but object A should not "reach through" object **B**
>   to access yet another object, **C**, to request its services

HTH,
Carlo